# Better performance with sudo "git clone" FreeBSD

Tags: git, freebsd

The performance of git clone as root is much better than from a normal user on a FreeBSD operating system. I don't see this issue on other operating systems.
Trace from user:

```
16:29:18.541291 git.c:462               trace: built-in: git rev-list --objects --stdin --not --all --quiet --alternate-refs '--progress=Checking connectivity'
16:29:18.541545 trace.c:415             performance: 0.000462180 s: git command: /usr/local/libexec/git-core/git rev-list --objects --stdin --not --all --quiet --alternate-refs '--progress=Checking connectivity'
16:30:49.264916 packfile.c:1659         /usr/home/***/***/.git/objects/pack/****.pack ***
16:30:49.266021 chdir-notify.c:70       setup: chdir from '/usr/home/***' to '/usr/home/***/***'
...
16:30:49.267952 trace.c:415  performance: 92.112003993 s: git command: git clone http://*****************.git
```

Trace from root:

```
16:39:25.639364 git.c:462               trace: built-in: git rev-list --objects --stdin --not --all --quiet --alternate-refs '--progress=Checking connectivity'
16:39:25.639652 trace.c:415             performance: 0.000523483 s: git command: /usr/local/libexec/git-core/git rev-list --objects --stdin --not --all --quiet --alternate-refs '--progress=Checking connectivity'
16:39:25.640623 packfile.c:1659         /usr/home/***/***/.git/objects/pack/****.pack ***
16:39:25.641093 chdir-notify.c:70       setup: chdir from '/usr/home/***' to '/usr/home/***/***'
16:39:25.642753 trace.c:415             performance: 1.451267882 s: git command: git clone http://***********.git
```

What is it connected with, and how can i fix it?

I can not understand what the problem is ... I could not find a solution to the problem on the Internet.

Comment: That's weird. I don't have a specific hint, but I'd try to isolate as many variables as possible. Does the same difference also happen when no network traffic is involved (i.e. you clone from a local directory). Does changing the clone destination matter (maybe home is a network drive, try in `/tmp`)? Does changing the git config file to an empty one have an effect?

Comment: Compare the environments of root and your user account.

Comment: That's a huge difference, 1.5s for root vs 92s for the user, something has to be wrong in the user configuration. I assume you've tried a few times, alternating between the two, making sure it's repeatable?